# How to make butter and sugar mixture into a breadcrumb consistency?

Tags: baking

I've been following a recipe for cinnamon biscuits which states to mix butter and sugar together until it forms a breadcrumb like consistency. Every time I attempt this is makes more of a creamy like consistency. I don't have a food processor which I've heard is ideal to use as they are quite expensive. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: The process you are asking about is called "cutting in the butter" @jolenealaska has given a great answer, but I wanted to give you some guidance. Buy a quality food processor. If you really like cooking as much as many of us do, you will find it indispensable. It saves _so much time_, and it saves your muscles. It's perfect for this task, and can turn it into a task that takes 15 seconds and no aching hands and finger. After a good set of pots and pans and utensils, food processor and stand mixer are two extraordinarily helpful time and muscle savers.

Answer (score 5):

Use *chilled* butter and don't touch it with your fingers unless you can be really fast about it, you don't want the butter to start to melt. Use a fork, a couple of knives or ideally a pastry cutter to cut up the butter and coat the cold little pieces of butter with the sugar.

[image: 1] [image: 2]

You can even use a cheese grater to grate the *frozen* butter and toss the grated butter with the sugar.

Answer (score 1):

As other people said, use butter from the fridge.

Usually, when making dough similar to what I guess you are making, I mix the butter with the flour and not with the sugar to get the same result, or with the flour and sugar.

I cut it into small pieces(about 1cm cubes) and then rub them between my fingers together with the flour/sugar. I think the knife method will take forever.

Comment: I agree that your method works well, but it does take some finesse to not melt the butter in the process. For foolproof and quick, the grating of frozen butter is a pretty cool trick.

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend a pastry cutter or stout balloon whisk (use it to stomp into the flour)...

The exact ratio of fat to flour makes a big difference there, +/- 10% can be significant ... if in doubt, use a bit less fat and help with small amounts of oil when stirring the dough together until the consistency is right. Same principle when adding non-fat liquid to that dough afterwards - a little at a time, the curve from dust to sludge is steep there.